# Redux Persist saving multiple data

Tags: react-native, redux

I am making use of https://github.com/cinder92/react-native-get-music-files to get the music files on a user's device with my app, I am making of use of redux persist so that when the music loads once on the user's phone and the user comes back to the app, it will just check for new music not in the `tracks` state array, it won't have to rescan for all the music, it will just check for new music in the background, but the state usually contains double data(it usually reloads the music, it will show music 1-5, then music 1-10) and It doesn't load all the music on the person's phone it just stops halfway, when I use normal states, i.e `this.setState` all the music on the users phone usually loads please what may I be doing wrong
This is my code below

**Store - index.js**

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' 
import rootReducer from "../reducers/index";
import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
  //  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
    timeout: 0,
  }
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)
export default () => {
  let store = createStore(persistedReducer)
  let persistor = persistStore(store)
  return { store, persistor }
}
```

**Actions- index.js**

```
export const addSong = song => ({type:
    "ADD_SONG", payload: song
});
export const RESET_ACTION = {
    type: "RESET"
}
```

**Reducers- index.js**

```
import{ADD_SONG,RESET} from "../constants/action-types";
const initialState = {
    tracks: []
};
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case ADD_SONG:
        let index = state.tracks.findIndex(tracks => tracks.id == action.payload.id);    
        if(index != -1){
            return state;
        }else{
        return { 
            ...state,
            tracks: [...state.songs, action.payload]
        }
        }
        case RESET:
        return initialState;
        default:
            return state
    }
}
export default rootReducer;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    Image,
    Dimensions,
    StatusBar,
    ScrollView,
    View,
    DeviceEventEmitter,
    FlatList,
    ActivityIndicator,
    AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native';
import Splash from './components/Splash';
import Home from './components/Home';
import MusicFiles from 'react-native-get-music-files';
import Permissions from 'react-native-permissions';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
//import store from "./store/index";
import index from './store/index';
const {store, persistor} = index();
import {connect, Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {addSong, RESET_ACTION
} from "./actions/index";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        tracks: state.tracks
    };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
      addSong: song => dispatch(addSong(song)),
      RESET_ACTION
    };
};

class reduxApp extends Component{
    millisToMinutesAndSeconds(millis) {
        var minutes = Math.floor(millis / 60000);
        var seconds = ((millis % 60000) / 1000).toFixed(0);
        return (seconds == 60 ? (minutes+1) + ":00" : minutes + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds);
      }
           componentDidMount() {
            this.props.RESET_ACTION;   
            this.setState({loaded: false});
            if(this.props.songs && this.props.songs.length > 0){
            this.setState({loaded: true})    
            }else{
            this.musicGetter();    
            }


           }
           musicGetter(){
            Permissions.request('storage').then(response => {
                this.setState({ photoPermission: response })
              })
              MusicFiles.getAll({
                  id : true,
                  blured : false,
                  artist : true,
                  duration : true, //default : true
                  cover : true, //default : true,
                  title : true,
                  cover : true,
                  batchNumber : 1, //get 5 songs per batch
                  minimumSongDuration : 10000, //in miliseconds,
                  fields : ['title','artwork','duration','artist','genre','lyrics','albumTitle']
                })
           }
           componentWillMount() {
        /*    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
                'onBatchReceived',
                (params) => {
                    this.setState({songs : [
                        ...this.state.songs,
                        ...params.batch
                    ]},this.setState({loaded: true}));
                }
            );*/
            DeviceEventEmitter.addListener(
                'onBatchReceived',
                (params) => {
                    console.log(params.batch);
                    this.props.addSong(params.batch);
                    this.setState({loaded: true});
                }, 
            );

        }
      async  asynccer(){

            try {
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:songs', JSON.stringify(this.state.songs));
              } catch (error) {
                // Error saving data
              }
        }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            timePassed: false,
            photoPermission: '',
            songs: [], 
            loaded: true,
            loading: false
        };
    }
  render() {
    if (!this.state.loaded) {
        return (
            <Splash/>
           );
    } else {
        return (
            <View style={styles.linearGradient}>
            <Provider store={store}>
            <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <Home songs={this.props.tracks}/>
            </PersistGate>
            </Provider>
            </View>
        );

    }
}
}
function connectWithStore(store, WrappedComponent, ...args) {
    var ConnectedWrappedComponent = connect(...args)(WrappedComponent)
    return function (props) {
      return <ConnectedWrappedComponent {...props} store={store} />
    }
  }
  const App = connectWithStore(store, reduxApp,mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
  export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
render() { 
        const lyrics = this.props.songs.map((song, index) =>
        <View style={styles.musicBox} key={index}>
        <View style={{width: 57, height: 59, borderRadius: 9, marginLeft: 15}}>
         <Image resizeMode="contain"
         style={{alignSelf: 'center', borderRadius: 9, width: 57, height: 59}}
          source={{uri: song[0].cover}}/>
          </View>
         <View style={styles.TextBox}>
          <Text 
          numberOfLines={1} 
          style={{fontFamily: 'nexaBold', fontSize: 20, color: 'white', flex: 1}}>
              {song[0].title}
          </Text>
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', }}>
          <Text 
          numberOfLines={1} 
          style={{fontFamily: 'nexaLight', fontSize: 10, color: '#917D7D', 
          marginRight: 5, }}>
              {song[0].author}
          </Text>
          <View style={{alignSelf:'center',width: 2, height: 2, borderRadius: 1, backgroundColor: '#917D7D',marginRight: 5}}>

          </View>
          <Text style={{fontFamily: 'nexaLight', fontSize: 10, color: '#917D7D'}}>
              {this.millisToMinutesAndSeconds(song.duration)}
          </Text></View>
         </View>
        </View>         
        );

        const music = 
            <ScrollView overScrollMode={'never'} keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>
            {lyrics}</ScrollView>;
        const shadowOpt = {
            color: "#000",
            border: 12,
            opacity: '0.08',
            radius: 12,
            x: 0,
            y: 1,
        };          
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View style={styles.linearGradient}>                                      
                {music}
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```